# Django email subject "EMAIL_SUBJECT_PREFIX" is ignored

Tags: django, wagtail, django-allauth

I'm using Django + Wagtail + Allauth and I want to change the subject when a user register or forget her/his password:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_SUBJECT_PREFIX = '[Django] '
```

While I set `EMAIL_SUBJECT_PREFIX` to '[Django] ', I'm having '[example.com] ' instead.

```
web_1  | Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"
web_1  | MIME-Version: 1.0
web_1  | Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
web_1  | Subject: [example.com] Password Reset E-mail
web_1  | From: webmaster@localhost
web_1  | To: me@me.com
web_1  | Date: Wed, 26 Feb 2020 15:04:41 -0000
web_1  | Message-ID: <158272948175.190.1882653498152410368@69079ce78170>
```

Do you know why ? And if there is another way to change the prefix ?

Comment: Email subjects not encoded properly: The text in templates/registration/ password_reset_subject.txt also appears with incorrect formatting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just found that I should use: `ACCOUNT_EMAIL_SUBJECT_PREFIX`.

Please notice that ACCOUNT_EMAIL_SUBJECT_PREFIX is an [Allauth  setting](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html) end not a Django core setting.

Comment: Is it necessary to have django.contrib.sites? In my django project neither EMAIL_SUBJECT_PREFIX and neither ACCOUNT_EMAIL_SUBJECT_PREFIX. The text in templates/registration/ password_reset_subject.txt also appears with incorrect formatting.